# Window.location working inconsistently in ComponentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to redirect the user to a native app by setting window.location to a custom uri, so if the user has the app installed it will open that page in the app.

Login Component:

```
componentDidMount() {
        const { match: { params: { domain } } } = this.props
        if (domain) this.setState({ domain })
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            window.location = `clickclock://login/potato`
       }

    }
```

it's render through react router:

```
<Route path="/login/:domain?" render={props => status ? redirect("/") : <LoginPanel {...props} onLogin={onLogin} />} />
```

The problem is that the redirect works when pressing this button that pushes the history to show the Login Component:

```
<Button text="Login" onClick={() => { history.push('/login') }} />
```

but it doesn't work when loading or reloading the page directly in that path.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you directly load the page, the routes mechanism fails.

If you are using Server Side Rendering then you should configure the `/login` route in the server side too.

If you are using just webpack (your site is a static site) then you should make sure there is a file named as `login.html` or so in the right folder.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you'll fix that issue by using the [`Redirect`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md) component from `react-router` like this:

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

/* some code */ 

<Route path="/login/:domain?" render={props => status ? <Redirect to="/"/> : <LoginPanel {...props} onLogin={onLogin} />} />
```

Comment: The thing is the component loads as intended, but the
 ```javascript
            window.location = `clickclock://login/potato`
```
of the componentDIdMount only works when mounting the component through a direct `history.push`, and I even think it's when the user action provokes this history.push. On a button click for example.

Comment: Could you do a repro case on codesandbox for instance ? Hard to tell from those few lines of code.
Have you tried the `Redirect` though ?

Comment: Yes, I've just tried `Redirect` to see if that solved the issue but it doesn't. The issue seems to be related with user interaction, if the `window.location` change isn't caused by user action it seems to be ignored, I'll try to do a codesandbox, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that a `window.location` change must be related to a user action to work (Button click for example). What I've done is a screen that asks the user what he wants to do, and based in the user's response I do or don't the `window.location` change.